# hadoop - Adding drives to existing cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloud, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-partitioning

I have a 4 node hadoop cluster set up , I am adding 3 more drives to each node to my cluster . I mounted my 3 drives in one of the nodes(master)and I added a property dfs.data.dir.If I do this , my datanode is not starting . Should I make changes to any other configuration file ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>4</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
<property>dfs.data.dir</property>
   <value>/app/hadoop/tmp,/media/hd1,/media/hd2,/media/hd3</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Can you tell me what is going wrong ?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `<value>` tag with a `</value>`.

Comment: Sorry I did close the value tag , I missed it while pasting it.